# Is the genetic query optimiser enabled by default?

Tags: postgresql

I read with interest about postgres' genetic query optimiser. Is this enabled by default? Is there a setting to enable it? Are there good rules of thumb of when to use it versus when now?

Doc link follows:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/geqo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration for the genetic optimizer is documented in the chapter "Query Planning" of the manual. Specifically the section [Genetic Query Optimizer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-GEQO)

The first configuration parameter that is listed there is:

> `geqo (boolean)` 
> Enables or disables genetic query optimization. **This is on by default**. It is usually best not to turn it off in production; the `geqo_threshold` variable provides more granular control of GEQO.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So whenever you run a query that has more tables in the FROM clause than specified by `geqo_threshold`, GEQO will be used.

If you want to see the effects of it, you could lower that value and compare those plans against plans done without it.